# Snmp V3 missing exceptions like "not in time window" or "wrong engine id"

Tags: sharp-snmp

I'm trying to handle situations when the report parameters are old or wrong.
for example,
if the engine time is "old" (delta time) I should receive "not in time window" exception \ errorcode
if the engine id is wrong I should receive "wrong engine id" eception \ errorcode

I couldn't find any reference in sharp snmp documentation.
I reproduce such scenarios and I'm getting NO errors, errorcode 0 and the result ends with some random data.

it's possible to handle \ extract those errors?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/blob/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpget/Program.cs#L222

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I thought it will be part of ISnmpPdu.ErrorStatus.